# Grouped dropdowns with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, list, data-binding

If I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```
$scope.Skills = [
    {
        ...
        Name: 'Skill',
        ...
        SubSkills: [
            {
                ...
                Name: 'Sub skill',
                ...
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

Two levels deep at all times as per example.

Is it possible to populate a dropdown options with both top level objects and sub level objects at the same time into something like this:

```
<select data-ng-model="model.Skill" data-ng-options="option.SubSkills.Name group by option.Name for option in Skills">
    <!-- workaround browser bug -->
    <option value="" label=""></option>
</select>
```

To obtain a single dropdown list with both Skills and Subskills selectable:

```
<empty option>
Skill 1
Skill 2
    Sub skill 1
    Sub skill 2
Skill 3
    Sub skill 1
Skill 4
Skill 5
```

You get the picture.

I tried to follow the example provided by [AngularJs Docs](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) but instead I get no Subskills and Skills are non-selectable:

```
$scope.colors = [
  {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
  {name:'white', shade:'light', notAnOption: true},
  {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
  {name:'blue', shade:'dark', notAnOption: true},
  {name:'yellow', shade:'light', notAnOption: false}
];
```

Which is combined with the following HTML:

```
<label>Color grouped by shade:
    <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in colors">
    </select>
</label><br/>
```

But because my data structure is already grouped I can't make this work.